# Drupal commerce show prices inclusive vat on product display

Tags: commerce

Is there a way to always display prices inclusive vat on product display?

My problem comes when a customer buys something and it´s shipped to non EU country - then it will display prices without vat.
if customer will make another order shipped to a EU country - then it will show prices without vat until shipping address is changed.

And I want it to always show prices inclusive vat on product display

I´m using EU_Vat module
extra price formatter , flexyformatter